# MatPaginator unexpected behaviour inside ngIf?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, pagination, angular-material

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgem23)

I have a material table as following:

```js
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
    ... Rows ...
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>  
<mat-paginator #MatPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[4]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

I need the table to be hidden when the variable `info` is false.

---

1. **Attempt 1:**

```js
<table *ngIf="info" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
```

It works fine but the pagination does not work when `info` is true and all rows are displayed on the first page.

---

2. **Attempt 2:**

```js
<table [hidden]="!info" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
```

Makes the pagination work, but when `info` is false the table is still displayed with no results.

---

3. **Attempt 3:**

Tried to sourround the whole table with a `div` and apply `*ngIf` to the div. Result: Same problem as in first attempt.

Tried to apply `[hidden]` to the `div` but still not hidding.

---

3. **EDIT: Attempt 4:**

Applied directly to the envolving `div` css `style="display:none"` and getting the same result as in attempt 3, the table is shown even if it has no values.

---

> Any idea on how to hide the table when `info` is false and show it
>   when `info` is true with a working pagination?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
 [hidden]="true"

<div [hidden]="true" >
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
      <ng-container matColumnDef="test">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Test. </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let exp"> {{exp}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>  
  <mat-paginator #MatPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6]" showFirstLastButtons> 
  </mat-paginator>
<div>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7djdu)

make sure to change your condition in [hidden]

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to add dynamic class and use that class to hide the table like

```
[ngClass]="{'hidden': !info}"
```

and in your style.css

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksgvv2)

Comment: Thanks, but your solution only works with a normal table, not an Angular-Material one with pagination, where the `*ngIf` bug is.

Comment: Updated with stackblitz

Comment: @Iñigo you'r using wrong condition if you want to hide if there is no item then it should be `*ngIf="info?.length"` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3mehr

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. The ngIf condition is not important here. If I set *ngIf="true" the paginator is not working. See stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the paginator inside a ngIf, otherwise, when you set `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator`, `this.paginator` is undefined. There is a solution if you REALLY want to ngIf it (tell me if it is realy necessary), but I recommend changing it to `hidden` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 solution:

**[hidden]** can be used instead of ***ngIf** and activation of the tab can be done using CSS properties.

```css
 .tableClass .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
          width: 160px !important;
        }
```

```html
<div [hidden]="true" class="tableClass">
     <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Tab1">
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab2">
        </mat-tab>
     </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using the `*ngIf` and `async pipe` in my template and pagination was not working. After some research I was able to make it work using the @ViewChild annotation and a set function so I decided to share my complete solution here :)

The `hidden` solution propose by other answers didn't work for me.

In my component.ts file:

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  /*
   We are using @ViewChild because of the ngIf with async pipe on the template
   When the data is emmited for the first time from the observable, we need to bind the
   pagination component with the datasource. This can be achieved with the code bellow.
  */
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    if(mp) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(your_data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
     }
   }
```

and in my template file:

```
// my observable with the async pipe
  <div *ngIf="raceList$ | async as races">
    <div class="mat-table-width">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      </table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"
                      showFirstLastButtons
                      aria-label="select page of races">
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
```

With this solution I was able to display the data in the table and make pagination work.